# Python webapp to set all query vars to a js object

Tags: python, web.py

I am building a simple web app with Python and web.py. My current challenge is to take all query vars (`web.input()`) and set a JavaScript object in the HTML template. However, I don't know how to ensure this gets rendered OK instead of a long string with encoding.

Thanks a million!

I have the following code in `app.py`, template HTML and content HTML:

`app.py`:

```html
import web

urls = (
  '/hello', 'hello',
  '/bye/', 'bye'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=True)
#test = "testwaarde"
test = web.input()
render = web.template.render('templates/', base='layout')

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return render.index("Templates demo",test, "Hello", "A long time ago...")

class bye:
    def GET(self):
        return render.hell_form("Templates demo",test, "Bye", "14", "8", "25", "42", "19")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Template:

```html
$def with (page)
<html>
<head>
<title>$page.title</title>

<!-- Digital Data Layer -->
  <script> 
   var test = "{{$page.path}}"
    var digitalData = {
      'page':{
       'path': '$page.path'
      }
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>You are visiting page <b>$page.name</b>.</p>
$:page
</body>
</html>
```

index HTML:

```html
$def with (title, **path,name, content)
$var title:$title
$var name:$name
$var path:$path
<p>$content</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close:

1. Move your call to `test = web.input()` to within your `GET()` methods, not at the top of the file. That's just a bug. (I know that's just your sample code, but it doesn't work.)
2. Within `index.html`, use

   ```
   $var path = path
   ```

   The using `var path: $path` sets the template variable to **a string representation** of path. You want to set it to the **dict**. That's one difference between the colon and the equal sign. Second, because it's '=', the right hand side is interpreted as python, so no leading '$'.
3. Within your template `layout.html`, change your javascript to something similar to:

   ```
   var test = "$:page.path";
   var digitalData = {
       'page': {
           'path': $:page.path
        }
   };
   ```

   You'll want to escape the data using `$:` rather than `$`. That's why you're seeing the encoded values. Also, you don't want to surround the final `$:page.path` with quotes to set `page.path` to an object, rather than just a string.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, this helps a lot! however the result i get now still contains <Storage ... > Is there a simple way to get rid of that? Much appreciated!

Comment: Sure. webpy's `<Storage>` class is derived from python dict. As long as your object isn't complex (and web.input() is not complex), simply cast it to a dict: `foo = dict(web.input())`. Then in your template, the value of `$:foo` will be usable as json within the javascript code: `var my_json = $:foo;`